# What's the abbreviation of these name in v6 sh source code?

Tags: shell, unix

[sh.c](https://v6shell.org/history/sh.c).
Names like TPAR, DSPR. Any guess is also welcomed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`TPAR` is an abbreviation for *this token is associated with a parenthesis*. Similarly, the other short identifiers are abbreviations for much longer descriptions of their function. You need to derive them from context (or ask the code's author).

Comment: Yup, the best way to find out the abbreviations of these names is going to the author. But I don't think Ken would have time to ask these simple question. A roughly guess would help me a lot in understanding the source code better. e.g. TPAR is very likely to mean `TYPE PARENTHESES` .